# Iframe on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am calling iframe within fancybox popup on HTML page. Iframe is having aspx page which shows some records from database. The issue I have is if number of records are zero then also it shows blank popup. I dont want to show popup when records are zero.
To show popup, I am calling Iframe using jquery as below. Just I want to put there condition for number of records. I am not getting how to do that. Please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function myFunction() {
        $.fancybox.open([{
            type: 'iframe',
            href: 'GetPopupNews.aspx'
        }], {
            padding: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance,
Mayura

Comment: will need to show where you call this. Consider passing record count to html as `data-` attribute and checking that value in your click handler

Comment: I am calling this on html page within 'head' tag

Answer (score 1):

As your number of records are displayed in the aspx page that is inside the iframe, there are two ways you can solve this:

1) Get the count of the number of records from the parent page *and then* decide if to popup the iframe if the count is more than zero.

2) In the GetPopupNews.aspx page, if the record count is zero, run javascript to close the iframe within which the page is open. From the iframe aspx, call some function on the parent window like so: `window.parent.closeBox();`

Comment: Yes.. Thnx.. But Parent page is HTML page from which I can not connect to database therefore I can not get number of records on html page

Comment: Then your only solution is the 2nd one. There is one additional thing you can do: Keep the popup hidden initially, and let the aspx page in the iframe check the result. Only if there are non-zero result, the page can call a function in the parent page to display the popup with the iframe (which would have already loaded and displayed its results).